# sqlite exception no such column

Tags: c#, sqlite

The following method should check if the record already exists in the table or no. But, I receive the syntax error "**no such column**".

```
 public void ifExist(int myId)
 {
     string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "ormdemo.db3");
     var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
     SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(db);
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM storeConsumption WHERE Id = ?"+ myId;

     int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar<storeConsumption>());
     if (count == 0)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("The record is NOT Existed");    
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("The record is Existed");
     }
 }
```

Although, still there is the same error. I would be thankful if you have an idea that how can I solve it?

**UPDATED:**  I could resolve this problem like this:

```
public async Task<Boolean>  ifExist(int id){

    var result = await sdb.databaseConnection().ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM storeConsumption WHERE Id = ?", id);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    if (result > 0) return true;

    return false;

}
```

Comment: uninstall your application intall again check it once.

Answer (score 2):

It seems caused by "Id=?". Please try to use following command line when you want to add parameters

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM storeConsumption WHERE Id = @myId";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myId",myId);
```

more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks John for your response. Visual Studio can not recognize the method Add. Actually, I just use 4 methods for my cmd.Paramater. Although, I added all the necessary libraries. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Updated: The following piece of code has been solved the error and it is working well:

```
public async Task<Boolean>  ifExist(int id){

    var result = await sdb.databaseConnection().ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM storeConsumption WHERE Id = ?", id);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    if (result > 0) return true;

    return false;

}
```